# GoogleChrome extension that deletes browsing history with one click from an icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

Im trying to make a google chrome extension that deletes all browsing history with one click on a icon located next to the url bar, this is my first extension on google chrome, i've made others for firefox, and i would like some guidance and ideas i think im quite close to my goal or at least in the right path, my current issue is the javascript document i know im missing code.

Javascript [TEST.js]

```
function TESTh() {
  chrome.history.deleteAll()
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(TESTh);
TESTh();
```

Manifest [manifest.json]

```
{
  "name": "TITLE TEST",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "DESCRIPTION TEST",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["TEST.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "history"
  ]
}
```

The following links are the tutorials i've been reading

```
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html
https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a sample trivial demonstration of Browsing Data API, it can help you to pick from here. Deletion may take time so you have to wait for message `"All data is Deleted..."` in console of extension for confirmation.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name" : "BrowsingData Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "Trivial Demonstration of Browsing Data",
  "permissions": [
    "browsingData"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
   function browsingdata(){
    chrome.browsingData.remove({
      "originTypes": {
        "protectedWeb": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
        "unprotectedWeb":true,// Set to true or true as per your requirement
        "extension":true    // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      }
    }, {
      "appcache": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "cache": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "cookies": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "downloads": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "fileSystems": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "formData": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "history": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "indexedDB": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "localStorage": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "pluginData": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "passwords": true, // Set to true or true as per your requirement
      "webSQL": true // Set to true or true as per your requirement
    }, function (){
        console.log("All data is Deleted...");
    });
}
window.onload=browsingdata;
```

For more information refer [browsing data API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData.html) to get idea of all methods etc.

Comment: Thanks @Sudarshan, that example indeed gave me a few ideas, too bad i couldn't make it work, i tried to "reverse engineer" the native Google chrome option to clear the browsing data [CTRL+SHIT+DEL or Menu/Tools/Clear browser data...] and i haven't read it all yet but i think there might be some useful stuff there, i also found this http://goo.gl/SXKpE wich is a chromium dev site and i got a few ideas from there too but im STILL FAR FROM SOLVING this :(

Comment: @Minnen: I have edited my answer with working version, it will simply delete every thing from your browser(set flags to false where ever necessary)

Comment: Thanks! @Sudarshan, being absolutely honest, i didn't properly read the link u provided in the [answer](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData.html), mea culpa, your first example did worked after all and that link had all the information i needed, thanks! i wish i could give you points :(, anyway i will add you info on the extension as dev (if you're ok with it), i will go head and make the options panel so users can choose which data they want to delete.