# Call background function of Chrome extension from a site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am looking for a function inside a webpage te activate a chrome extension.

Imagine that http://www.example.com/test.html contains:

```
<script>
hello();
</script>
```

And my background page contains the definition of the `hello` function:

```
function hello() {
    alert("test");
}
```

How can I make sure that the Chrome extension's background page's `hello` is called when `test.html` calls `hello();`?

Comment: No, you can't for obvious security reasons. The extension would need to expose its API on purpose

Answer (score 15):

Before a web page is able to call a background page's function, the following problems need to be solved:

1. Be able to use `hello();` from a web page. This is done by [injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) a script defining `hello` using Content scripts. The injected function communicates with the content script using a custom event or `postMessage`.
2. The content script needs to communicate with the background. This is implemented through [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).
   *If the web page needs to receive a reply as well:*
3. Send a reply from the background page (`sendMessage` / `onMessage`, see below).
4. In the content script, create a custom event or use `postMessage` to send a message to the web page.
5. In the web page, handle this message.

**All of these methods are asynchronous, and have to be implemented through callback functions.**

These steps need to be designed carefully. Here's a generic implementation which implements all of the above steps. What you need to know about the implementation:

- In the code-to-be-injected, use the `sendMessage` method whenever the content script need to be contacted.
  Usage: `sendMessage(<mixed message> [, <function callback>])`

contentscript.js

```
// Random unique name, to be used to minimize conflicts:
var EVENT_FROM_PAGE = '__rw_chrome_ext_' + new Date().getTime();
var EVENT_REPLY = '__rw_chrome_ext_reply_' + new Date().getTime();

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = '(' + function(send_event_name, reply_event_name) {
    // NOTE: This function is serialized and runs in the page's context
    // Begin of the page's functionality
    window.hello = function(string) {
        sendMessage({
            type: 'sayhello',
            data: string
        }, function(response) {
            alert('Background said: ' + response);
        });
    };

    // End of your logic, begin of messaging implementation:
    function sendMessage(message, callback) {
        var transporter = document.createElement('dummy');
        // Handles reply:
        transporter.addEventListener(reply_event_name, function(event) {
            var result = this.getAttribute('result');
            if (this.parentNode) this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            // After having cleaned up, send callback if needed:
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                callback(result);
            }
        });
        // Functionality to notify content script
        var event = document.createEvent('Events');
        event.initEvent(send_event_name, true, false);
        transporter.setAttribute('data', JSON.stringify(message));
        (document.body||document.documentElement).appendChild(transporter);
        transporter.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
} + ')(' + JSON.stringify(/*string*/EVENT_FROM_PAGE) + ', ' +
           JSON.stringify(/*string*/EVENT_REPLY) + ');';
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);


// Handle messages from/to page:
document.addEventListener(EVENT_FROM_PAGE, function(e) {
    var transporter = e.target;
    if (transporter) {
        var request = JSON.parse(transporter.getAttribute('data'));
        // Example of handling: Send message to background and await reply
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            type: 'page',
            request: request
        }, function(data) {
            // Received message from background, pass to page
            var event = document.createEvent('Events');
            event.initEvent(EVENT_REPLY, false, false);
            transporter.setAttribute('result', JSON.stringify(data));
            transporter.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
    }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message && message.type == 'page') {
        var page_message = message.message;
        // Simple example: Get data from extension's local storage
        var result = localStorage.getItem('whatever');
        // Reply result to content script
        sendResponse(result);
    }
});
```

A Chrome extension is not complete without a manifest file, so here's the `manifest.json` file which I used to test the answer:

```
{
    "name": "Page to background and back again",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://jsfiddle.net/jRaPj/show/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

This extension was tested at http://jsfiddle.net/jRaPj/show/ (containing `hello();` as seen in the question), and shows a dialog saying "Background said: null".
Open the background page, use `localStorage.setItem('whatever', 'Hello!');` to see that the message is correctly changed.

Comment: @Xan `chrome.extension.sendMessage` is an alias for `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. Are you perhaps confused with `chrome.extension.sendRequest`?

Comment: I'm not confused; but the function is retired completely (not mentioned in the docs) and yet keeps popping up in new code because of lingering old sample code. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495052) to mark it as deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

There is a builtin solution to [Send messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) to the extension

`mainfest.json`

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

Web page:

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var editorExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

Extension's background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
      openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

No, with your above code because of [background page(s) architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#arch)

Yes with [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

**Demonstration Using Content Scripts**

***manifest.json***

Registering content scripts myscripts.js

```
{
"name": "NFC",
"description": "NFC Liken",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"],
"content_scripts": {
    "matches": "http://www.example.com/*",
    "js": [ "myscript.js"]
  },
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "sync-icon.png",
"default_title": "I Like I Tag"
}
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But no the deal.. Can I also ron these function inside the myscript.js 

function clearhist () {

var millisecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
var oneWeekAgo = (new Date()).getTime() - millisecondsPerWeek;
chrome.browsingData.remove({
  "since": oneWeekAgo
}, {
  "appcache": true,
  "cache": true,
  "cookies": true,
  "downloads": true,
  "fileSystems": true,
  "formData": true,
  "history": true,
  "indexedDB": true,
  "localStorage": true,
  "pluginData": true,
  "passwords": true,
  "webSQL": true
}, callback);
}

Comment: @WoutervanReeven: No, you can not put this code directly in `myscript.js`, but you can achieve this by making indirect call to code by placing this in `background` page and through message communication. refer [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637715/not-receiving-any-data-from-webpage-to-content-js-of-chrome-extension/13638508#13638508) let me know if you need more information

Comment: So I need to call the javascript function in the background js script. In the html of page http://www.example.com/test.html in the to do something to call the script inside the chrome extension. 

Background html
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script>
function hello() {
alert("test");
}
</script>

      </body>
    </html>

myscript.js
hello();

Comment: @WoutervanReeven: Yes, put the code for `browsing data API` in `background js`, and call the function from content script using message communication; Refer [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557159/googlechrome-extension-that-deletes-browsing-history-with-one-click-from-an-icon/13557728#13557728) for more information

Comment: @WoutervanReeven: You can not directly make a call with hello(); it has to be invoked through message communication .