# IS it possible to run chrome apis under normal web pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi i want to use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html api under my website

is it possible to use this api at my website if i install a chrome addon or its possible only under extension?

Comment: Yes, but indirectly, via message passing (page -> content script -> background page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call background function of Chrome extension from a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777887/call-background-function-of-chrome-extension-from-a-site)

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55316.