# How to tell when a page action is clicked when the page action has a popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked:

> `chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tabs.Tab tab) {...});`
>
> Fired when a page action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the page action has a popup.

So how do I tell when the page action is clicked if it DOES use a popup?

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645977/bypassing-the-no-popup-if-i-want-a-javascript-to-run-when-extension-clicked/17646630.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a popup is set, clicking on the button causes the popup page to be loaded and displayed. At the same time, the `onClicked` event will not be triggered. So, if you want to detect a click when a popup is set, put some code in popup.js.

For instance: if your code without popup looks like:

```js
// background/event page
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // Do something
});
```

Then remove that piece of code from the [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) / [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) page, and put the code in popup.js:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Do something, e.g. send a message to content or background script
});
```

If it's important to keep the logic in the background page, e.g. if you're initiating a http request, database access, etc., then use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to notify the background page that the button is being clicked:

```js
// popup.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('pageActionClicked');

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message === 'pageActionClicked') {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

If you have to know the current tab (like the `tab` argument in the `pageAction.onClicked` event), use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query):

```js
// Inside the DOMContentLoaded or onMessage event listener:
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    // Do something with tab
});
```