# Chrome.socket listener in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, google-chrome-extension

So I've searched very thoroughly and tried a lot of things to create a **TCP or UDP listener for the Chrome.socket API in the browser in JavaScript**. I am very confused now. So far I have tried using:

- WebSockets
- WebTCP sockets
- WebRTC
- PeerJS
- Node net module in chrome extension

And several more small options. So far these 'options' all don't seem to work properly. The closest I got was getting a readyState of zero in the browser. The server accepts the connection, but the readyState of the socket in the browser just stays zero (means still connecting).

I have two questions.

**Is it possible?**
Is it even possible to listen to incoming TCP/UDP connections made from a Chrome extension on a sperate website with only client-side JavaScript?

**How?**
If so, how would I be able to create this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Is it even possible to listen to incoming TCP/UDP connections made from a Chrome extension on the browser side?" What do you expect to do the listening? A Chrome app? A website? A website run inside a browser with a particular Chrome app installed? What do you expect to make incoming connections? A Chrome app? A website? An application?

Comment: A@apsillers I'm trying to do the following: chrome extension (=server) creates socket and waits for a client to connect -> website (=client) creates socket and asks for connection on a certain address+port where the chrome.socket is listening -> chrome.socket server accepts the connection and sends a message back to the website -> log this message on the website.

Comment: @user2730863: AFAIK, Chrome extensions have more direct ways of communicating with page JS.

Comment: @SLaks but what if the page JS is not delivered by the chrome extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call background function of Chrome extension from a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777887/call-background-function-of-chrome-extension-from-a-site)

Comment: @user2730863: The way to communicate between arbitrary webpages and your extension is with **[content_scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)**. You don't need anything as complicated as the process you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you will never be able to create raw sockets in pure client-side code.

Protocols like WebSockets or WebRTC require that the server explicitly acknowledge the protocol and allow you to connect.

Comment: This question is posed in the context of browser extensions. What do you mean by "browser-side" code? Chrome apps can certainly create sockets using [`chrome.socket`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html).

Comment: @Rob_W With browser-side code I mean JavaScript that can be run directly in the browser without the usage of a chrome extension. So just client-side JavaScript. Sorry for my vague description.

Comment: @RobW: No; it actually isn't.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for your reply, but would I be able to 'translate' the data I wish to send from the chrome extension (server) to data that can be read by a websocket client before I send the message? Or am I missing a fundamental part of the meaning/usage of tcp sockets here?

Comment: @user2730863: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you want to use WebSockets, all you need is a WebSocket server.  You don't need an extension.

Comment: @RobW I also initially assumed the OP was writing a Chrome app, but I now think the OP was (deliberately) trying to use Chrome app API functions in normal website code. It's tremendously unclear.

Comment: @apsillers sorry for explaining it unclear. I'll try to explain my question as short as possible: how can I communicate with a chrome.socket from outside the extension?